# Using CSS attribute selector with styled components for icons

Tags: css, sass, next.js, styled-components

I'm using NextJS for React, SSR and styled-components (with hashing). So far I managed to build main CSS structure with Sass.

nextjs.config.js

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')
module.exports = withSass({
  cssModules: true,
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    importLoaders: 1,
    localIdentName: "[hash:base64:5]",
  }
})
```

The problem is I cannot use an attribute CSS selector; for icons, usually I define font-family like below

```
[class^='icon-'] {
  font-family: 'fonticon'
}
.icon-foo {
  &:before {
    content: '\someunicode';
  }
}
```

when I run build and `.icon-foo` class successfully converts to some hash and match with the CSS. But I cannot use an attribute selector here.

I know it's impossible to convert this kind of selector, but is there any solution, like giving a exception rule for cssLoaderOptions for example,

```
excludeClasses: /^.icon-/
```

so I can keep my classes as they are just for the icons?

I know I can give font-family to `<i>` tag, but I want to avoid that if possible.